# How to overwrite to a file each time function is called and append to the file inside the function in python?

Tags: python, file, io

I have a function like this:

```
def process_corpus(xml_dir, top):
  for dir_file in os.listdir(xml_dir):
    dir_file_path = os.path.join(xml_dir, dir_file)
    if os.path.isfile(dir_file_path):
        with open(dir_file_path) as f:
            page = f.read()
            v = mapping(dir_file_path, top)
            print "filename"
            print dir_file
            for i in range(len(v)):
                f1 = open("/Users/akritibahal/Downloads/stanford-corenlp-2012-07-09/file1.txt".format(i), "w")
                if v[i] == 1:
                    print (str(i+1) + ":" + str(v[i]))
                    f1.write (str(i+1) + ":" + str(v[i]) + " ")

                f1.close()
            f.close()
```

This function opens a directory containing files and then reads each file.
I want that each time the function is called, data should be overwritten to the file, file1.txt, and when each file is read and then computation if done for it then data should be appended to that file (file1.txt). How to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow but you can open a file for appending by passing `"a"`': `open(the_filename, "a")`.

Comment: You need to add some clarification to your question as it is very unclear what it is you are asking

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation for open()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open):

```
with open("file1.txt", "w") as file1:
    file1.write("The file is truncated and overwritten with this")

with open("file1.txt", "a") as file1:
    file.write("This is appended to the end of the file, regardless of the current seek position)

with open("file1.txt", "r") as file1:
    data = file1.read() # Cannot write to the file here

with open("file1.txt", "r+") as file1:
    data = file1.read()
    file1.write("This mode allows you to both read and write to the file")
```

UPDATE:

You can also check out [this blog](http://freepythontips.wordpress.com/2014/01/15/the-open-function-explained/) which explains the `open()` function nicely.